# eLisp. check if return value of (read-event) is a graphical character

Tags: emacs, character

I'm trying to check if the return value of `(read-event)` is a graphical character. Example: `a` (97) is a graphical character. `return` is not a graphical character. `f1` is not a graphical character and so on. I tried a lot of ways to do that, but nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `char-displayable-p`? `C-h f` tells you:

> **`char-displayable-p`** is an autoloaded Lisp function in `mule-util.el`.
>
> `(char-displayable-p CHAR)`
>
> Return non-`nil` if we should be able to display `CHAR`.
>
> On a multi-font display, the test is only whether there is an
>   appropriate font from the selected frame's fontset to display
>   `CHAR`'s charset in general.  Since fonts may be specified on a
>   per-character basis, this may not be accurate.

But that says that it expects `CHAR` to be a character.  So you might want to also test to make sure that it is, using `characterp`.

(In fact, `characterp` might be all you need: `(characterp (read-event))`. It depends on whether you care if a given character is displayable in your environment, i.e., given the fonts you have.)

You can often find a function with a name like `char-displayable-p` using `apropos`. Try, for instance:

`M-x apropos RET char display RET`

That shows you something like this:

> Type `RET` on a type label to view its full documentation.
>
> **`char-displayable-p`**
>
> > Function: Return non-`nil` if we should be able to display `CHAR`.
> >
> > Properties: `autoload`
>
> **`glyphless-char-display`**
>
> > Variable: Char-table defining glyphless characters.
> >
> > Properties: `char-table-extra-slots` `variable-documentation`
>
> **`glyphless-char-display-control`**
>
> > User option: List of directives to control display of glyphless characters.
> >
> > Properties: `standard-value` `custom-version` `custom-type` `custom-options` `custom-set` `custom-requests` `variable-documentation`
>
> **`nobreak-char-display`**
>
> > Variable: Control highlighting of non-ASCII space and hyphen chars.
> >
> > Properties: `variable-documentation`
>
> **`tabulated-list-glyphless-char-display`**
>
> > Variable: The `glyphless-char-display` table in Tabulated List buffers.
> >
> > Properties: `variable-documentation`
>
> **`update-glyphless-char-display`**
>
> > Function: Make the setting of `glyphless-char-display-control` take effect.

Comment: You are right! When I press any "non graphicable character", this function doesn't return a character! I make use of characterp. Thanks!